# How do I put an arrow at the end of `\utilde`?

Tags: math-mode

A book uses some kind of a `\utilde` symbol with an arrow at the end of it to denote a path in a directed graph.

[image]

`u \leadsto u'` and `\utilde{p}` give the parts respectively.

[image]

How do I get the symbol pointed out by the red rectangle?

Comment: Isn't this just a font issue? The `\leadsto` symbol in `wasysym` and `latexsym` both look pretty much like the one you boxed. And examining the `p` and `u` glyphs, you are certainly not using the same font as the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$u\overset{p}{\leadsto}u'$
\end{document}
```

[image]